# Spring Security custom authentication provider with custom login doesn't put error parameter to the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I've read and applied the [Creating a Custom Login](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html) tutorial for custom login page and  also custom authentication provider to my project.

As far as I understand from the documentations, spring security handles the login error by putting a parameter to the url such as "login?error=blabla".

But in my situation, no matter what user enters except for the true credentials, no request parameters are shown. But normal logins (meaning true logins) works fine.

Is there something I miss ?

**CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl implements UnalAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        UserDetails user = null;

        try{
            user = (UserDetails) customUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        }
        catch(UsernameNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("User name not found");
            throw ex;
        }

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
        }

        if (!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
    }


    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**spring-security-config.xml**

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"  access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login"  access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/access-denied"  access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login"  default-target-url="/main" always-use-default-target="true"/>

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>

        <headers>
            <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </headers>

        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control expired-url="/login"  />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProviderImpl" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

After giving some thought, I also decided to remove all intercept-url, thinking that might be a unintented redirection because of those... But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance you miss a configuration parameter in your `<form-login>` section, namely the `authentication-failure-url`.
This is where you instruct Spring Security to redirect your failing login attempts.
Try to add it as follows:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" <!--other configurations--> authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />.
```

And, of course, take care of managing the `error` parameter in your custom login jsp.